# Spring Boot - No Mapping for GET /new

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am currently working on a FAQ Web Application in Spring Boot. My index page is working fine but if I want to open another HTML Page I get a 404 Not found Error Page in my browser and Intellij says:

```
WARN 8068 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /new
```

How can I fix that?

IndexController:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private FAQService service;


    @RequestMapping("/")                                          
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        List<FAQ> listFaqs = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listFaqs", listFaqs);

        return "index";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/home")                                           
    public String backHomePage(Model model) {
        List<FAQ> listFaqs = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listFaqs", listFaqs);

        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/new")                                        
    public String showNewProductForm(Model model) {
        FAQ faq = new FAQ();
        model.addAttribute("faq", faq);

        return "new_product";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)           
    public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("faq") FAQ faq) {
        service.save(faq);

        return "redirect:/";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")                                       
    public ModelAndView showEditProductPage(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("edit_faq");
        FAQ faq = service.get(id);
        mav.addObject("faq", faq);

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")                                     
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
        service.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3" lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/static/css/styles.css}"/>
<head>
    <title>WebApp</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center"><h3 th:inline="text">Welcome [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]</h3></div>
<div class="logout-btn" th:align="center">
    <a th:href="@{/logout}"><button>Logout</button></a>
</div>
<div align="center">
    <br>
    <h1>Manage Excel Files</h1>
    <th:block th:include="/_menu"></th:block>
    <div class="ncontent-btn">
        <a href="/new"><button>New Entry</button></a>
        <a th:href="@{/excel/export}"><button>Export to Excel</button></a>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

POM.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

All my HTML files are in /resources/templates path.

Comment: Try to add the method on the request mappings, example: @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: @FelipeBonfante I tried that already and it did not work unfortunately

Comment: Do you have a small, runnable sample that demonstrates the problem. There does not seem to be anything wrong from what I can see here. You can use `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping`, but it should not make a difference. Also, what Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: I tried `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping` aswell and as you already said it made no difference. Currently I am using Spring Boot Version 2.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning "new_product", in the /new method.
You have to create a new_product view (new_product.jsp / new_product.html..) and do whatever you want to inside, then it will be ok and you'll get a 200 response.

If your file already exists, maybe the path is not correct and you have to configure it. Try to put the html file in static folder otherwise add your path in your application.properties

Comment: I tried moving the `new_product.html` file into the static folder but still the same 404 not found error.

Comment: Try to add properties
spring.mvc.view.prefix=<path to your views folder>
spring.mvc.view.suffix=<.jsp or .html>